# Conditionally using type defined in template parameter

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to define a type the following way: if `T` has `SomeType`, then use `T::SomeType`, otherways use some other type. But if I try the following, the compiler compiles if `T` has no type called `SomeType`:

```
template<typename T>
struct
{
    using SomeType = std::conditional_t<hasSomeType<T>, T::SomeType, SomeOtherType>;
    //...
    //...
};
```

`hasSomeType` is a (c++20) concept and everything here is known compile-time so I wondered why it can't work. Is this doable somehow with a workaround?